# IIS - Error : Method not found 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.SsFlags'

Tags: iis, 500-error

When I try to access one of my IIS websites I get the error `500.19 Internal server error`. I was told it comes from IIS permissions, is it?

The problem is that when I try to access anything (click on a folder on my website, click on Application Pools or even sometimes do nothing), I get the following error:

> Method not found : 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.SslFlags
>
> Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_SslFlags()'.

What am I suppose to do with this?

I tried to reinstall IIS via Windows Features and reinstall .NET frameworks, nothing changed.

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you running?

Comment: I run it locally, it's running on Windows 10 anniversary and IIS 10.

Comment: The error doesn't make much sense, but I don't think it is a permission problem. Check that the file: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` has a version number of `10.0.14393` This file as the method `Microsoft.Web.Administration.SslFlags`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf The version of the dll is as you say.

Comment: @Elfayer Did you find the cause for this problem?